# Search in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, http-status-code-404

My problem, when I searched in **WP** on **English** language, it's working Good, but when I start to search on **Russian** or **Japanese** it's redirect me on page {site.com}/search and shows 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

You might have zero records for that query. Start Searching for those results that could match with your database.
I mean to say search that content which is already in data base, Otherwise you will be redirected to 404 Page.

Comment: If I seek on English, It's shows me on russian language too. because all posts on three language.

Answer (score 0):

Do you using custom search script or any hook for search function?
Or you using default WordPress search form?

Comment: Are you sure your template is not using any hook on search functions?

Comment: Yes i sure. Problem in: when i typing on english then go to search {site.com}/search/{search_query} but when i typing on other languages then go to {site.com}/search but if I set url {site.com}/search/{search_query_another_language} its OK

Comment: Yes this can cause 404 error. Also you can check this for your custom search options [link]http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page